# Conditional code in preprocess_page function?

Tags: theming

I need to add a conditional code in a **my_theme_preprocess_page** function.

The conditional should be like:

if the loaded node has a field called **background_image** and the value for this field is not empty, then is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you. Note:

- It doesn't check the node type.
- It adds the variable `has_background_image` on *any* page that has `$vars['node']` available in `hook_preprocess_page`, and *only* on those pages.
- `$has_background_image` will be true if the field isn't empty (that's the only check).

.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $field_name = 'field_background_image';

  if (!empty($vars['node'])) {

    $node = $vars['node'];
    $items = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);

    $vars['has_background_image'] = $items ? TRUE : FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what do you want to do exactly, but I suppose you want to pass it as another variable.

```
function my_theme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Make sure node object exists
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    if (isset($vars['node']->field_background_image[0]['uri'])) {
      $vars['has_background_image'] = true;
    } else {
      $vars['has_background_image'] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your page.tpl.php you could use $has_background_image to check if the value is true/false.

If this is not what you asked, edit your question to make your goal clear.

Comment: I think this will set `$has_background_image` to true when the field's attached but empty.